# Run exe on windows virtual machine from osx terminal

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I have installed a command line executable on a windows virtual machine on my mac. I would like to launch this exe from osx terminal. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare Fusion comes with CLI `vmrun`, which, however is not placed in the PATH by default.

```
'/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun' -h
```

will tell you that there's a `runProgramInGuest` subcommand for running commands inside a given VM.